# Generating Text out of curves and lines

Tags: c++, fonts, text-rendering, freetype2

I am working on a project in which i use a library to export geometry as IGES. This library only allows me to export lines. I want to create labels for my export by rendering some text next to it. For example, i can export a circle and i want to render a text next to it using only lines that shows the radius.

I can already use bezier curves so i thought of using vector graphics. Checked out some SVG parsers, [Freetype library](https://www.freetype.org/index.html). My initial thought was to access curves on glyphs and generate my own method for text rendering. However, it seems like Freetype generates bitmaps and i cant really use bitmaps with this library i am  using. Also even using glyphs seems a bit overkill because glyps contains outline of letters but i actually do not need an outline. Only centerline would be fine in my case.

[image: Glyph example]

My question is, is there a way i can import some font file or something which contains control points of curves that are centerlines of letters and numbers so that i can generate text in my IGES export? Or is there an easier way to access glyph lines using Freetype? I would appreciate if anyone has any experience with fonts and give me some tips. Thank you in advance

Comment: If the looks weren't important (or "retro" were fine), I would design my own "font" made out of lines, perhaps based on the common alphanumerical LED design.

Comment: Seems evident that Freetype library renders the font (that is it's purpose). Converting outline in center-line is far from trivial (if possible). Maybe you can use the raster from freetype and create linear trends (statistics) between near dots.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes the looks are not main concern. I will take a look at designing my own design. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Hershey fonts. A series of fonts designed for pen plotters. Starting in the 1960s at the US Navy, it now has a huge repertoire of Glyphs.

That said, it seems like it might be tricky to get hold of the actual vector data in a format you can use. http://www.whence.com/hershey-fonts/ or https://github.com/frankrolf/python-hershey might be a good start.

They're often built-in to plotter software, so that might be another option.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually forgot about this question. The solution I found was to use CNC fonts which are single line. Therefore, I never had to deal with double lines here.